# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an iOS app that implements **Google Cloud Messaging**.

I want to receive the authorization token and print it on screen.

I installed everything necessary and I wrote the code following a tutorial on YouTube.

That's my code:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *getton;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GoogleCloudMessaging.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize getton;

- (void) dealloc {
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LaunchScreen.storyboard" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [self registerDeviceToken: deviceToken];
}

- (void) registerDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Device Token: %@", deviceToken);
    NSMutableString *string=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    int length=[deviceToken length];
    char const *bytes=[deviceToken bytes];
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.2hhx",bytes[i]]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(connectionWebRegister:)withObject:string];
    [string release];
}

-(void) connectionWebRegister:(NSString *) deviceTokenString {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://serviceProvider/registerTokenId?tokenId=%@&app=",deviceTokenString]];
    NSLog(@"APNS URL : %@",url);
    NSData * res = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    getton=deviceTokenString;
    if (res!=nil) {
        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [res bytes] lenght:[res length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
        [response release];
    }
    [pool drain];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"test");
    NSMutableDictionary * test = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MESSAGE"
                                                     message:[test objectForKey:@"alert"]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}    
@end
```

ViewController.h and ViewController.m are both empty.

But when simulator starts, it crashes with this error:

> <'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle' > with an < Thread 1: signal SIGABRT > error in
>   Main.m .

I have searched  a lot on internet to solve that problem, but I could not solve it.

So, are there somebody, who can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `LaunchScreen.storyboard` in project in main bundle?

Comment: You can't use a storyboard file as if it were a NIB file.  You need to get a reference to the storyboard and then use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you storyboard with mentioned name in question exists then

You should use,

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboardobj=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LaunchScreen" bundle:nil];

self.viewController = [storyboardobj instantiateInitialViewController];
```

instead of

```
   self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LaunchScreen.storyboard" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: So, Is swift better than Objective-C? what about you?

Comment: Both have some advance and disadvantages but swift is newer technology made to overcomes limitations of objective c, so you can say it better. `You should only discuss original post related discussion in comments. If you have another type of query then you should ask separate question`